# Insert or Append registers when field has Default Value in a TQuery

Tags: sql, delphi, insert, append, insert-update

I want to insert or append in a query, which has column with default value in database, but this column is not set when a register is included from Delphi.

I thought in change my clauses of appending and inserting, instead I remove the fields that have default value and are null, but I dont know if it's the easy way.

My table is:

CREATE TABLE TABLETEST (
    ID     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FIELD  INTEGER DEFAULT 10
);

My Delphi code to see if is inserting the correct value is:

```
Query1.SQL.Clear;
Query1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM TableTest order by ID');
Query1.Open;
Query1.Last;
ID := Query1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;

inc(ID);
Query1.Insert;
Query1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger := ID;
Query1.Post;

inc(ID);
Query1.Append;
Query1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger := ID;
Query1.Post;

Query1.ApplyUpdates;
Query1.CommitUpdates;
```

** Query1 in a TQuery

Comment: When I do an insert or append in a Query, and do a Post.

Comment: By `register`, I presume you mean `auto-incremented value`. In that case, you don't assign one in your code; the database will assign it for you when the `INSERT` is done. Depending on the RDBMS you're using, you can usually retrieve the value from the DB after that is done, but I can't offer suggestions as to how to do that because you didn't include a tag for the DBMS you're using.

Comment: @KenWhite from his comment I believe he is saying "register" means filling insert or append followed by a post, in this case he fills the "ID" field, but not the "FIELD" field, but receives NULLS instead of the default value of 10

Comment: @JasperSchellingerhout: If that's what he means, then that's what the question should ask. I'm not certain, however, and I'm not spending time answering a question just to be told that's not what was meant. (I can easily answer the question either way, but not until the poster makes it clear what is being asked.)

Comment: @KenWhite and @Jasper only OP can say for sure what he means, but in portuguese, `register` and `record` are the same word (`registro`)... so in my understanding, he means `record`, i.e., a row in the table.

Comment: Maybe this depends on database, but Firebird assigns `NULL` to a field with default value if the insert query (note that `insert` and `append` are the same thing in `SQL`, AFAIK) explicitly says so, e.g. `insert into table (columnA, columnB) values (10, NULL)`. I don't know how `TQuery` behaves, but that might be why you're not getting your expected default value in `FIELD`.

Comment: Have you considered using another database access component? I'm pretty sure that `Zeos` handles this correctly and only assign values in the query to the fields you set. And it doesn't depends on BDE.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified SQL Server who is used, but as GabrielF says

for Firebird when execute

> insert into table (columnA, columnB) values (10, NULL)

`columnB` value will be `NULL` no matter that is set to 10 by default in database.

To be sure that field value will be set by default, you may use TQuery **OnNewRecord** event as :

```
procedure TDataModule1.Newrecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  Query1.FieldByName('FIELD').AsInteger := 10; //SET DEFAULT
end;
```

Or if you want to use "pure" SQL in Delphi (as in IbExpert Script executive) you may use :

```
Query1.Sql.Text := 'Insert into table (ID) values (<value>)';
Query1.ExecSql;
```

In this case there will be no value in field 'FIELD' and default value will be used.

Comment: But when i execute:


insert into table (columnA) values (10)


Value of columnB will be the default value.

Comment: Query1.insert will fire OnNewRecord event so when you execute FIELD value will be 10 already

Comment: You also may set `FIELD INTEGER NOT_NULL DEFAULT 10` to test what delphi sent to database or better may use `SqlMonitor`.

Comment: Sorry I do not read well. Yes, If you execute  `insert into table (columnA) values (10)` there will be default value of columnB.

Comment: -1. This doesn't solve the question. With this solution, you're not using the column default value at all. You're just inputing some value (and overwriting an explicitly one) on client side.

Comment: @GabrielF And what. What is the difference ? It is not explicitly said in question, that default value should be determined only on server. In this case a trigger Before Insert could be used. Like : `if new.field is null then new.field = 10`.

Comment: The real question is ,

I want to use the same resource that I can use directly accessing the database (with IBExpert) .
Direct access to the database by giving a post or commit, the default value is inserted when uninformed field value.

For Delphi, I want to know the possibility of this happening the same way, without the use of query triggers or events.

Comment: @ValMarinov What is the point of defining a default value in the schema if you're going to set it on the client side? It's clear to me that OP wants to use server-side default value.

Comment: @GabrielF There is many points to do this.Lets stop those discussion. Ask a question and I will answer.

Comment: @ValMarinov Actually I asked a rhetorical question There's definitely no point in reimplementing database schema default values in client side (unless you're using a deficient library, like Tales Furuno is, in which case, there's no point in even defining schema default values). But I reverted downvote, since your second solution (now present after your edit) does solve the actual problem and uses schema default value, though not a good solution, IMO.